# Install TP Link Wifi Switch and problems along with it

Tags: light-fixture, home-automation, wifi

Similar to [Trying to identify the neutral in my switch box for home automation switch.](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/98819/trying-to-identify-the-neutral-in-my-switch-box-for-home-automation-switch?newreg=dcdde2e50d214a5cab96d751b82cfb31) , I have an issue regarding installation of Wifi switch.

The switches I got were WiFi switches [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01EZV35QU/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EZV35QU).

Now the problem was, it needs 4 wires to be connected, when I opened the faceplate of the switch, I did not find any Neutral wire.
As suggested by TP-Link they need Neutral wire. http://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-1128.html Has someone encountered such issue?

Pictures attached after I opened current switchboard with all the wires. I assume it may be 4 wires already but not sure and would like your advice/suggestions for the same.

I have connected 3 wires currently and wifi switch has power but when i turn it on, the light blinks for a second and that's it. Doesn't stay on. Also, it keeps showing orange wifi light signal.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have a bundle of white wires nutted together at the back of the box. Is there a reason you think those are not all neutrals?

Comment: The reason was ,I dont have much of an idea about it. But your hint helped. Indeed it was neutral.